# JS Date Mask is not working in Clone

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, datepicker

When i am using JS date mask for single field is working fine.
But when same thing i used in clone part,it is not working on specific text field.Its upgrade in above part. And that field is still vacent.

Comment: Please show your code or a demo on jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to re-initiate the JS mask, try this after clone :

```
$(":input").inputmask();
```